# Use Jalali date instead of Gregorian date in patternfly-timeline

Tags: timeline.js

How I can use Jalali date instead of the Gregorian date in the [patternfly-timeline](https://github.com/patternfly/patternfly-timeline)?
This is a force for me to use Jalali in the patternfly-timeline. I mean that the x-axis should show Jalali date format.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show your effort to us, what have you tried so far and what kind of errors have you gotten?

Comment: I don`t know how do this. I want to change the XAxis format to shamsi or Jalali date instead of Gregorian. You know I want to change locale and time format to Asia/Tehran but how?